# Calling methods inside .dll File in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a DLL file in c# with the following content:

```
namespace GenerateMemo
{
class GenerateMemo
{
    public MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string port;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    public void SqlConnect(string _server, string _port, string _database, string _uid, string _password)
    {
        string connectionString;

        connectionString = "SERVER=" + _server + ";" + " PORT=" + _port + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        _database + ";" + "UID=" + _uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + _password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }

    public void sqlNonQueryN(string query)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

and I dont know how to call those methods inside the file. I am using Visual Studio and already imported it as reference. Please tell me how to use my DLL file. I need to use those methods in another project. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: make the "class GenerateMemo" a "public class GenerateMemo" reference the Library and you can use it

Comment: Default access modifier for a class is internal so like this you could only use it within the same assembly

Comment: You seem to have a load of private variables which never get used. Your Query method also closes the connection which may not be what you want if you're planning on doing further queries against the DB as you'd have to re-run the SqlConnect method each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to make your `GenerateMemo` class `public` to use it in another assembly. Right now it is `internal` (default access modifier of class).

Then, if you already added this dll as reference to your project - basically you need to create instance of your class and call it methods.

```
var memo = new GenerateMemo();
memo.SqlConnect(....)
```

and so on.

And make sure you've included `using GenerateMemo;` namespace in the file where you planning to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A lot more readable:

```
public class GenerateMemo
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;

    private string server, database, uid, password;
    private uint port;

    public GenerateMemo(string _server, uint _port, string _database, string _uid, string _password) //constructor
    {
        server = _server;
        port = _port;
        uid = _uid;
        password = _password;
    }

    private void BuildConnection()
    {
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        builder.Server = server;
        builder.Port = port;
        builder.Database = database;
        builder.UserID = uid;
        builder.Password = password;

        connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    public void sqlNonQueryN(string query)
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            BuildConnection();
        }
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```